# No persiste un array dentro de un componente tras un llamado a una API

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-carousel, react-axios

Esta es mi primera consulta e intentare ser lo mas breve y descriptivo posible.

Estoy armando una pagina de peliculas basado en el desafio de Alkemy, quiero ir un poco mas alla para poder incluirla en un portfolio en lo pronto.

La pagina esta realizada en React+ReactBoostrap de donde me traigo el Carousel.
Mi primera intencion es realizar algo similar a lo que hago para renderizar las Cards individuales de cada pelicula.

Tengo un context, que importo en el componente con la funcion apiCall, que recibe un URL y me traigo tambien el movieList que vendria a ser el array de las peliculas resultante de pegarle a la api. Esto me funciona en otros componentes dentro del context la funcion es esta:

```
const [moviesList, setMovieList] = useState([])
const apiCall = (url) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const endPoint = url
        axios.get(endPoint)
            .then(res => {
                const apiData = res.data
                setMovieList(apiData.results)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [setMovieList])
}
```

Ahora bien, en el componente que idente como Landing, invoco apiCall con el endpoint que considero y luego quiero renderizar las imagenes y los titulos dentro del carrousel.
Esto, solo me funciona mientras lo voy escribiendo y voy viendo los resultados, cuando le doy a recargar, todo se rompe y el apiCall me devuelve undefined, sospecho que debo utilizar un useEffect dentro del comoponente Landing??? Estoy un poco mareado.
He aqui el componente en si:

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import { FavsContext } from '../../context/FavsContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Landing() {
   
    const { apiCall, moviesList } = useContext(FavsContext)
    apiCall("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=7caf46531396de643008db1c668fdc90&language=es")
   
    const movies = moviesList
        
    return (
        <>                       
            <Carousel fade>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[0].backdrop_path}`}
                        alt="First slide"
                    />
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>{movies[0].title}</h3>
                        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[1].backdrop_path}`}
                        alt="Second slide"
                    />

                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[2].backdrop_path}`}
                        alt="Third slide"
                    />
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                        <p>
                            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
                        </p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        </>
    )
}
export default Landing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta que no se reciban los datos de la API moviesList será undefined.Y Petará por que intentará buscar un atributo llamado title (por ejemplo) de un undefined.

La solucion es chequear que existe movesList, i si existe pinta por pantalla lo que quieras. Mientras sea underfined no pintes.

```
return(
{ moviesList ? 
    <>
    // return si existe movieList
    </>
  :
    <>
    <h3>Cargando datos...</h3>
    </>
}
)
```

Comment: Excelente! Me salvaste!!!!